# Is there a way to use the rotation of an object to instantiate UI images?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a UI popup over an object so that they hover over the object like the blue X in the picture below:

[image: City popup over the country]

However, I'm having trouble with the positioning and rotation of the image.

I tried using `Vector3.forward` to instantiate the object in front of the countries, but they all went off to one side. The `Vector3.forward` looks like this:

[image: Vector3.forward of countries]

I got pretty much the same result using `transform.forward` as well, just that all the lines went straight up instead of to the side.

Is there a way to instantiate the UI image in front of the countries with the same rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"forward" does not mean "in front of", it is just a shorthand for (0,0,1)

If you want a position in front of a specific position on a globe, just do something like this:

```
var newposition = positionOnGlobe + (positionOnGlobe - positionOfGlobeCenter).normalized * distanceToGlobe;
```

If you also want the rotation you could probably do something like

```
Quaternion.LookRotation(positionOnGlobe - positionOfGlobeCenter);
```

But be aware that this will have issues when near the poles.

Also note that it is fairly common to draw widgets like in your example at the objects position, but in such a way that it is on top of everything else. I'm not familiar with Unity, but I would expect it to have some form of HUD-functionality that could be used for such purpose.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. As for the "HUD-Functionality", I'm using a World Space Canvas that renders UI in the world space, which I could use a separate camera to render, but I'd like to add some depth to the UI, which is why I opted for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

if u want an object to have the same rotation as the parent of the object. If i'm not mistaken you can use

```
Quaternion.Identity();
```

This means to have no rotation at all

Comment: This is wrong, when in parent object, if you don't set the rotation it will be the same as parent, if you want to set it to default you can use Identity

Comment: yes that is what i meant, but when the object rotates based on the parent the rotation of the parent effects the position of the child objects.